# How do I create a centered GLFW window?

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm looking for the SDL equivalent of

```
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL window", 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, windowFlags );
```

for GLFW. I can center the glfw window after its creation with the below code, however, for a split second, the window is shown non-centered. So it doesn't look smooth.

```
    // init glfw
    if (!initGLFW())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // create main window
    int count;
    int windowWidth, windowHeight;
    int monitorX, monitorY;
    
    GLFWwindow* gWindow;
    GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count);
    const GLFWvidmode* videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitors[0]);
    // width: 75% of the screen
    windowWidth = videoMode->width / 1.5;
    // Aspect ratio 16 to 9
    windowHeight = windowWidth / 16 * 9;
    
    glfwGetMonitorPos(monitors[0], &monitorX, &monitorY);

    gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Engine v" ENGINE_VERSION, NULL, NULL);
    if (!gWindow)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        std::cout << "Failed to create main window" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowPos(gWindow,
                     monitorX + (videoMode->width - windowWidth) / 2,
                     monitorY + (videoMode->height - windowHeight) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344):

> By default, newly created windows use the placement recommended by the window system. To create the window at a specific position, make it initially invisible using the [GLFW_VISIBLE](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_VISIBLE_hint) window hint, set its [position](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_pos) and then [show](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_hide) it.

#### Example

Using your code above, you would add a call to [`glfwWindowHint`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga7d9c8c62384b1e2821c4dc48952d2033) before `glfwCreateWindow` like so:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
```

and once you have positioned the window where you would like it, make a call to [`glfwShowWindow`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga61be47917b72536a148300f46494fc66) like so:

```cpp
glfwShowWindow(gWindow);
```

Depending on your use case, it may also be prudent to reset the window hints using [`glfwDefaultWindowHints`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#gaa77c4898dfb83344a6b4f76aa16b9a4a) after creating the window, to ensure that future window creation isn't modified.

Putting all that together, I have something like:

```cpp
if (!glfwInit())
{   
    return -1; 
}   

int count;
int windowWidth, windowHeight;
int monitorX, monitorY;
    
GLFWwindow* gWindow;
GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count);
const GLFWvidmode* videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitors[0]);
windowWidth = videoMode->width / 1.5;
windowHeight = windowWidth / 16 * 9;
    
glfwGetMonitorPos(monitors[0], &monitorX, &monitorY);

// (1).  Set the visibility window hint to false for subsequent window creation
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);

gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Engine v", NULL, NULL);
if (!gWindow)
{   
    glfwTerminate();
    std::cout << "Failed to create main window" << std::endl;
    return -1; 
}   

// (2).  Reset the window hints to default
glfwDefaultWindowHints();

glfwSetWindowPos(gWindow,
                 monitorX + (videoMode->width - windowWidth) / 2,
                 monitorY + (videoMode->height - windowHeight) / 2); 

// (3).  Show the window
glfwShowWindow(gWindow);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer! It works. Looking much better now!

Comment: Sounds good @user13742796. If you think that's answered your question, you can mark it as accepted.